# git - how to get the full message from git merge --log

Tags: git, git-merge

After using `git merge --log --no-ff --no-commit` or `git merge --log --squash`, a long commit message is created.

But the message is cut i.e `...` at the end and does not list all commits.

How do I get the full message?

I checked the files in `.git/MERGE_HEAD` and `.git/SQUASH_HEAD` and it also contains the short message with `...`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the `--log` option is actually `--log<=n>` (from [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)):

In addition to branch names, populate the log message with one-line descriptions from at most `<n>` actual commits that are being merged. See also [`git-fmt-merge-msg`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fmt-merge-msg.html).

So by specifying a large number for `n`, you should see all the commits in the merge log message.
By default, only the first 20 commits are listed.

The config setting `merge.log` can also be used to specify that number.