# Retaining Git Commit History in commit message when Merging branches in Git

Tags: git, merge, commit, git-merge, gerrit

Is there a command or option in Git that I can use when merging one branch into another so that the entire commit history / the commits that are getting merged show up in the commit text. 
So that whenever I do a git log I can also see all the commits that were merged as part of this merge commit?

Comment: Is `git merge --log` what you’re looking for?

Answer (score 2):

As [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688441/retaining-git-commit-history-in-commit-message-when-merging-branches-in-git#comment51318597_31688441), [`git merge --log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) does list the files to be merged (and append them to the actual message you could specify in `git merge -m "..."`).

But the actual command to use is:

```
git merge --log=1000 <other options depending on your merge>
```

Don't forget to use a large enough number for the `--log` option: by default, only 20 commits are listed: see "[How to get the full message from `git merge --log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13507892/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

To make this easier for future merges, you can also add the option to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
...
[merge]
        log = 1000
...
```